# counting the number of digits in a larger number

Tags: python, math

I am currently trying out Project Euler and one of the question is calculate 2^1000, and count the number of digits. I can easily do it for 2^15 but the issue with 2^1000 is that when I calculate it, it's given in scientific notation, so it's hard to sum the digits.

```
import math

def power(x):
    y_p=1000*math.log(x,10.0)
    y=math.pow(10,y_p)
    return y

if __name__=="__main__":

    ans=power(2)
    a=str(ans)
    print a
    sum=0

    for i in a:
       if i == ".":
          print "encountered ."
       elif i == "e":
          break
       else:
          sum=sum+int(i)

    print sum
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You want the sum of the digits or the number of digits?

Comment: Maybe given a number in scientific notation there is another way to get the number of digits instead of counting all of them in the "normal notation"? Think about it. There are also other ways to explicitly calculate the number of digits which don't needto explicit result of 2^x.

Comment: Alright, here's a hint. Write the first few values (maybe upto 2^16) down and look for a pattern. The problem does not require a computer.

Comment: This is probably http://projecteuler.net/problem=16 Euler problem #16, which is about the sum of digits, not the number of digits.

Comment: @itdoesntwork I don't see much of a pattern in [A001370](http://oeis.org/A001370)

Comment: Look at every fourth one starting from the first.

Comment: @itdoesntwork: could you be explicit about what you're seeing?  I'd be quite surprised if there were a simple formula, but then again I often miss the obvious.

Comment: Define S(n) to be the sum of the digits in 2^n. Then, S(4*n)=6n+1   EDIT: at least, that's how it looks for the first few tests.

Comment: @itdoesntwork while it works rather well for the fourth column [here](http://hpaste.org/57161), it breaks down.

Comment: @danr touché!  I tend to overuse inductive reasoning :|

Comment: @itdoesntwork: that's not true.  Take n=8.  S(4*8) = 58, but 6*8+1 = 49.  A quick search only revealed 22 values for which it *is* true.  Digits simply don't work like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To calculate 2^1000 in Python use `2**1000`. Using floating point functions like `math.log` and `math.pow` you are likely to get inaccurate results.

Now, here is how to do it:

```
l = str(2**1000)
digits = [int(digit) for digit in l]
print sum(digits)
```

The first line converts the number to a string in base 10 representation.The second line iterates on the characters and transforms the string to a list of digits. And the third prints their sum.

Comment: Why is `math.pow` less accurate than `2**1000`?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the easier method is to use log (or log10) in python. log10 has enough precision for this and can even solve 2**1000000 instantly without taking any space.

```
from math import log10
ans=int(1000*log10(2))+1
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers address how to sum the digits in a large number, but if your question is indeed on how to get the *number* of digits then just do

```
largenumber=2*1000
int(math.log(largenumber,10)+1)
```

or

```
len(str(largenumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using long()?

```
import math

def power(x):
    y_p = 1000 * math.log(x, 10.0)
    y = math.pow(10, y_p)
    return long(y)  # convert to long since we know it is an integral value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ans = power(2)
    a = str(ans)
    print a
    print len(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use integer arithmetic, `int`s in python does not overflow, so no need to do the floating point calculations. Calculate the power yourself:

```
def pow(a, b):
    n = 1
    for i in range(b):
        n *= a
    return a
```

which is O(n). You can also try the O(lg n) method:

```
def pow(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    temp = pow(a, b/2)
    if b % 2 == 0:
        return temp * temp
    return temp * temp * a
```

Calculate the sum of digits as you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using double precision and use arbitrary length integers instead:

```
  sum([ int(i) for i in str(2 ** 1000) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

To work this problem, use integer math and convert the result to a string:

```
>>> digits = str(2 ** 1000)
>>> len(digits)              # count the digits
302
>>> sum(map(int, digits))    # sum the digits
1366
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to count the number of digits of a big integer is

```
int(math.ceil(math.log10(big_integer)))
```

For example:

```
>>> big_integer=2**100
>>> print int(math.ceil(math.log10(big_integer)))
31
>>> print big_integer
1267650600228229401496703205376
```